# Converting code from C# to Java - Bit manipulation, Int64 to long

Tags: java, c#, bit-manipulation

I'm trying to convert this snippet from C# to java. The C# snippet is correctly returning the value `3259945`, the java code is incorrectly returning `-16855`. I'm completely useless at bit manipulation and have no idea where to even start. Can anyone help?

If people need the input variables I'll try to get the buffer byte array as a hex string so I can put it up. The `startIndex` I'm using is `26`.

C# snippet:

```
Int64 mantissa = ((Int64)(buffer[startIndex] & 0x7F) << (8 * 2))
                        | ((Int64)buffer[startIndex + 3] << (8 * 1))
                        | ((Int64)buffer[startIndex + 2] << (8 * 0));
```

Java Snippet:

```
long mantissa = ((long)(buffer[startIndex] & 0x7F) << (8 * 2))
                | ((long)buffer[startIndex + 3] << (8 * 1))
                | ((long)buffer[startIndex + 2] << (8 * 0));
```

Comment: In the C# example, have you tried using `long` instead of `Int64`?

Comment: I guess that `buffer` is `byte[]`? Take care that in Java bytes are signed

Comment: @DFord `Int64` is `long`. `Int64` is the actual struct name and `long` is just an alias.

Comment: @Aominè i know they are the same and should compile the same, but based on the code, that is the first think I thought to try.

Comment: `The startIndex is 26`. However, without knowing what is in `buffer` this code cannot be run. Could you provide the values for `buffer[startIndex]`, `buffer[startIndex + 3]`, and `buffer[startIndex + 2]` when you get the result `3259945`?

Comment: 3259945 is `0000_0000_0011_0001_1011_1110_0010_1001` in (Java long) binary, and -16855 is `1111_1111_1111_1111_1011_1110_0010_1001`  (Windows Calculator in programmer mode is helpful for these kinds of conversion problems)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, in .NET a byte is unsigned (0 to 255) and in Java it is signed (-128 to 127). To normalize it, you need to use the `& 0xFF` mask.

```
long mantissa = ((long)(buffer[startIndex] & 0x7F) << (8 * 2))
            | ((long)(buffer[startIndex + 3] & 0xFF) << (8 * 1))
            | ((long)(buffer[startIndex + 2] & 0xFF) << (8 * 0));
```

In the first case, you don't need this mask because the sign bit has been cleared by 0x7F.

Comment: instead of `((buffer[startIndex] & 0xFF) & 0x7F)`, just `(buffer[startIndex] & 0x7F)` is needed because the sign bit has been cleared by 0x7F